# setOnClickListener scope on dynamic added elements

Tags: android, event-listener

I am adding programatically and dynamically some elements (buttons and text views) with android. I also need to set the setOnClickListener event for each of these buttons and from that event execute some action on the click of button:

```
do
{
    EditText txt1 = new EditText(this);
    EditText txt2 = new EditText(this);
    Button showtxt = new Button(this);
    linearLayout.addView(showtxt );
    linearLayout.addView(txt1);
    linearLayout.addView(txt2);
    showtxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
           String aaa= txt1 .getText().toString();//HOW TO ACCESS txt1 and txt2 from here
           String bbb= txt2 .getText().toString(); 
       }
    }
}
while(somecondition)
```

I am almost new to android. How can I access to txt1 and txt2 in the click callback function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the define the variables where they will have class wide scope:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    EditText txt1;
    EditText txt2; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        txt1 = new EditText(this);
        txt2 = new EditText(this);
        ...
```

Now your onClick function will be able to see `txt1` and `txt2`.

**Alternatively**

Since you appear to be creating a lot of `txt1` and `txt2` in one LinearLayout, you can pass your Button a reference to its EditTexts:

```
do {
    ...
    // EditText[] array = { txt1, txt2 };
    //  is the short version of
    EditText[] array = new EditText[2]; 
    array[0] = txt1;
    array[1] = txt2;

    showtxt.setTag(array);
    showtxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           EditText[] array = (EditText[]) v.getTag();
           String aaa = array[0].getText().toString();
           String bbb = array[1].getText().toString();
           Log.v("Example", aaa + " " + bbb);
       }
    });
} while(some condition)
```

This may not be not ideal, however without any further context I cannot guess your ultimate goal. Hope that helps!

**Last Suggestion**

If we call the Button and two EditTexts a row, you could store each row in a ViewGroup or View of its own. Say you wanted to have background colors for each row:

```
View row = new View(this); // or this could be another LinearLayout
row.setBackgroundColor(0x0000ff);

// Create and add the Button and EditTexts to row, as in row.addView(showtxt), etc
...
linearLayout.addView(row);

showtxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View row = v.getParent()
        String aaa = ((EditText) row.getChildAt(1)).getText().toString();
        String bbb = ((EditText) row.getChildAt(2)).getText().toString();
        Log.v("Example", aaa + " " + bbb);
    }
});
```

Comment: the  goal is simple: creating new elements and adding the click event with reference to the new elements. I like the second solution but I guess if the first will work?

Comment: @albanx I updated my answer. The first solution requires a unique `txt1`, `txt2` for every "row", since you are using a loop it will require a lot of variables. So the second or third option is best, depending on what you want in the end.